# iOS Drawing App considerations

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing

I 'm building a medical app, which, at some point, enables the user to draw.

Because the drawing is minimal at most points, I 'd been using vectored graphics,but there is a case that a full-screen note should be drawn.

What's the most appropriate way to handle `touchesMoved`?
The point is basically to have antialiased lines drawn so the user can see them while `drawing`. But should I call 
`[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` each time `touchesMoved` is called, to update the entire full screen drawing?

Or should I keep the untouched UIImage in a cache and write on a new UIImage and redraw it while drawing, then when `touchesEnded` is called to merge?

How would an "eraser" should be implemented then? (the background is not white; It may have a body png, in which case simply by overwriting with white won't work).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might find it useful to watch Apple's WWDC videos, for example Session 506 WWDC 2012 "Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance". It shows simple path drawing application and shows how it can be optimized.

Comment: check this may be helpful for https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html